# Как подключить frontend к backend?

Tags: php, laravel, backend

Как подключить frontend к backend?

Сайт был Laravel 5.7 + VUE. Сейчас был полностью написан с нуля frontend на JS (самописный).

Т.е. нужно старый backend оставить (Laravel 5.7) и к нему подключить новый frontend.

Как я понимаю, нужно переписывать старый backend под новый frontend или нет?

Comment: нужно переписывать новый фронтэнд под старый бэкэнд

Comment: У меня уже есть готовый frontend, т.е. мне нужно либо переписывать frontend под старый backend, либо переписывать backend под новый frontend?

Comment: Я вам однозначно ответил

Comment: @Alex frontend не пишут просто так. Его с нуля делают в расчете на связь с каким то конкретным бакендом. Поэтому совершенно не ясно что же сейчас такое преставляет из себя фронт если у него нет функционала взаимодействия с баком

Comment: Ваш бекэнд должен возвращать `json` хотя бы. И как верно подметил @Mike  фронт всегда связан с беком. Очень интересное решение писать фронт не зная что тебе отдаёт бекенд)